# How to change text when hover is registered

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a text change whenever the user hovers such as the following below:

[image]

When the user **hovers**, I would like the **word "HI"** to **change to something else**, in which in this case **"BYE"**. However, what I tried is not working:

```css
.word_box span{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.word_box:hover span {
    content: "Bye";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "word_box">
    <label>The text beside will change when hovered</label>
    <span id="changing_text">Hi</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `content` on span but you can use it on pseudo elements like `:after`

For more info see here [CSS content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) and go to `Formal definition applies to:`

Also, i would suggest you don't use `label` element outside a form or if it doesn't represent a caption for another element. `label` element has a lot of advantages when used with inputs but if you don't need it, use `<p>` or `<span>` instead. You can even leave it as plain text inside the div if you don't have other elements.

```css
.word_box:after{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    content: "HI";
}

.word_box:hover:after {
   content: "BYE";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "word_box">
      The text beside will change when hovered
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it possible to not add a transition delay to it then?

Comment: 'content' property can't be animated. It's changing the content entirely. Not a color or a position. But you can use 2 different pseudo elements and position them absolute on top of eachother and animate them from opacity 0 to 1 BUT that was not in the scope of your original question. So if my answer solved your original problem, please don't forget to rate is as accepted so other users can use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.hi:after{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    content: "HI";
}

.hi:hover:after {
   content: "BYE";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "word_box">
  The text beside will change when hovered <span class="hi"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```